# can we give @QueryParam of type boolean a default value null?

Tags: java, jax-rs

can we give @QueryParam of type boolean a default value null ? if yes, how do we do it?

this is how I tried to do it but I still get false as default value:

```
@POST
public String setMethod(
        @QueryParam("value1") @DefaultValue("null") Boolean value1)
```

Comment: default value for Boolean is  null only

Answer (score 0):

You should try without `DefaultValue`. As `value1` is not a primitive it should stay `null`.

So like this :

```java
@POST
public String setMethod(
        @QueryParam("value1") Boolean value1)
```

following the spec:

> If @DefaultValue is not used in conjunction with @QueryParam, and the query parameter is not present in the request, the value will be an empty collection for List, Set, or SortedSet; null for other object types; and the default for primitive types.

Regarding your example -->  `new Boolean("null")` is actually equals to `false`.

So the result is normal.

`BTW` : Null should not be a valid option as a Boolean is a binary value either 0 or 1. Once it crosses into the tri-state (null, false, true) it's no longer a true Boolean and maybe if it is acceptable preferable to switch to enum value.

What about something like this ?

```java
public enum Value {
    A ,
    B,
    ABSENT
}

@POST
public String setMethod(
        @QueryParam("value1") @DefaultValue("ABSENT") Value value1)
```

Comment: I don't understand, if user did not insert any value, how can I get null ? I dont want to get false. I want it as indication that user did not insert any value.

Comment: if the query-param `value1` is not set to the post request... `value1` should have null pointer reference.

Comment: but I see "false". even when using boolean or Boolean. when user did not insert any value we get false.

Comment: I updated my answer.. can I see your code now please ?

Comment: So I will always get false as default value for boolean/Boolean ?

Comment: Nope "false" for boolean but null for Boolean

Comment: but I am getting "false" in both of the cases

Comment: which version ? Weblogic or SPring boot ?

Comment: to be more accurate we get the default value false only when user insert illegal value such as empty string.

Comment: I am not sure which version

Comment: yes it is normal... check the `Boolean.parseBoolean` method..  what it does -> `"true".equalsIgnoreCase("input");` so everything but  "true" will return false"

Comment: DId you see my updated answer -> Switch to Enum-based solution